# Converting PostgreSql timestamp query to MS SQL/Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, epoch

I'm currently  in the process of converting some basic sql scripts from Postgresql to Azure Sql. I'm newbie to sql, but I really can't understand epoch/unix time in Azure SQL / SQL Server. My application is using bigint epoch time as event timestamp and I want to make a housekeep script for the database and for the table where events are stored.

How do you work with epoch time **intervals** in MS or Azure SQL? What would be the equivalent in Azure SQL to the following query?

```
SELECT count(*) FROM info_event WHERE event_time < (SELECT cast(EXTRACT(epoch FROM current_timestamp - INTERVAL '1 MONTH') AS bigint) * 1000);
```

Comment: There are plenty of examples of how to convert a date and time value to a epoch here; what were wrong with those examples? What didn't you understand about them or why don't they work for your scenario?

Comment: I can't understand how to work with epoch time interval in MSSQL

Answer (score 0):

The solution was.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE epoch_column < (SELECT cast(DATEDIFF(second,'1970-01-01 00:00:00',(DATEADD(month,-1,GETDATE())))AS bigint)* 1000 );
```

Thanks for the help!